# Is there a word in French like this: est-ce-qu'

Tags: vocabulaire

So for French homework we have been given a list of words that we need to unscramble to make a sentence that makes sense, and in one of them there is a word which I have no idea what it means, and I am wondering if it could be a typo?
The word is:
est-ce qu'

I was looking around and found a word spelt like this:
est-ce que

Answer (score 4):

*Est-ce qu'* is the required [contraction](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/pronunciation/contractions/) of [est-ce que](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/expressions/est-ce-que/) in front of a vowel or mute h; for example,

*Est-ce qu'il y a du pain ?* - Is there any bread?

Answer (score 4):

"*est-ce qu'*" and "*est-ce que*" are the same. "*est-ce que*" becomes "*est-ce qu'*" when placed before a vowel.

Both are used to start a question.

For example :

- "est-ce que **t**u m'aimes ?" ("Do you love me?")
- "est-ce qu'**e**lle m'aime ?" ("Does she love me?")